# Inserting a number into dynamic array in C

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I am a new to C and I need to make a function that inserts a number to a 2D dynamic array depending on what is its last number in octal representation. I tried doing something like this.
Function generating an array:

```
void genArr(int m, int n, unsigned int** arr) {
    arr = (unsigned int**)malloc(m * sizeof(unsigned int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        arr[i] = (unsigned int*)malloc(n * sizeof(unsigned int));
    }
}
```

Function to insert numbers:

```
void insertToArr(unsigned int** arr) {
    unsigned int num;
    printf("Enter a number: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if (num != 0) {
            switch (num % 8) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    arr[1][i] = num;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    arr[2][i] = num;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    arr[3][i] = num;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    arr[4][i] = num;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    arr[5][i] = num;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    arr[6][i] = num;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    arr[7][i] = num;
                    break;
            }

        }
        else if (num == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But I keep getting exception error:

> > Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF630C019DE in App4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000010.

I'm stuck and don't really know what is wrong.

Comment: This whole switch/case can be replaced by `arr[num % 8][i] = num`. Your handling of `0` is not clear though - looks like it is retaining the previous value of array, which could be uninitialized.

Comment: The “generate array” function doesn't return a pointer to the allocated memory or modify the variable in the calling code.  You should probably return the pointer to the allocated space.  Otherwise, you need a third asterisk in the function signature and appropriate adjustments in the function and calling code.

Comment: You assign `arr` within the function, this has no effect outside the function. You need to dereference the pointer that is passed.

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong but should I change function "generate array" from void to `int` and then return a pointer to the first element of array? (something like `return arr[0][0]`). I know I can't return an array from function but don't really know how to return the pointer to the allocated space.

Comment: `genArr` completely ignores its 3rd parameter.   Why bother passing it?

Comment: You can't return an array, but you can return a pointer to its first element.  eg `unsigned int ** genArr(int m, int n) { unsigned int **arr = malloc(m * sizeof *arr); ...; return arr; }`

Comment: I implemented all these things and works ( I think ) but I now need to create a function to reduce the size of that array only to the elements that the user has entered and then print it (now it prints m*n elements  of `-842150451`). Is there an easy way to free all the memory slots that weren't used?